# Using a variable within the blog posts array query - posts_per_page as variable

Tags: wp-query

I am trying to use a variable that my content person can change when editing pages to display a different number of blog posts.

Here I have declared the variable:

```
<?php
while( have_rows('social_grid_settings') ): the_row();
    $number_of_blog_posts = get_sub_field('number_of_blog_posts');
?>
```

This has been checked and the variable is correct.

However when placed inside the query it doesn't seem to register it and displays all posts:

```
<?php
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'post',
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'category_name' => 'social-grid',
    'posts_per_page' => $number_of_blog_posts,
);
$arr_posts = new WP_Query( $args );
```

If I state a static figure '1' instead fo the variable it works.

Am I allowed to use a variable in this way?

Can anyone help me get this variable acting as it should?

Thanks, Jason.

Answer (score 0):

Instantly figured this out once I posted this - anyone who is struggling in the future:

```
'posts_per_page' => "'" . $number_of_blog_posts . "'",
```

Thanks, Jason.

Comment: You don't need the `"'"` around the number.

Comment: Thanks @fuxia. This works now, I believe. But I am unable to save my page when I update this variable value in the backend. It just says saving for ages (tested up to an hour).

Comment: Your answer wasn't wrong, it just had some code that wasn't necessary. I don't really see what to discuss. :)

Comment: @fuxia - I was having an issue with using an outdated version of the plug in ACF - Advanced Custom Fields. Now I have updated this it works swimmingly! Thanks for your persistence and politeness!

Comment: You shouldn't need to add quotes around the variable. What output do you get if you do `var_dump($number_of_blog_posts)`. You can also cast the variable using `'posts_per_page' => (int)$number_of_blog_posts,`